# get ViewModel variable to Html Component

Tags: html, zk

I want to load set a class for a HTML componenet `<h:li />` like this :

```
<h:li class="@load(vm.className)" />
```

but I can't and I can't use a ZK componenent.

Any suggestion will be welcome, Thank you

***EDIT***

here's the error :

```
org.zkoss.zel.ELException: The identifier [class] is not a valid Java identifier as required by section 1.19 of the EL specification (Identifier ::= Java language identifier). This check can be disabled by setting the system property org.zkoss.zel.impl.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK to true.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because "class" is a Java keyword (i.e. you cannot use it as a name). So zk uses "sclass" instead to work around this.

So, try this: `<h:li sclass="@load(vm.className)" />`

To help understand what is going on: If you write something like `<component property="something" />` in zul, zk will at some point call `component.setProperty(something)`. So in your case, even without "class" being a Java keyword, it would have complained that there is no `setClass` method on `li`.

If you have trouble setting a property in the future, just open the Java class of the component you are trying to create and check whether it actually has a setter for the property.

---

**Edit** after feedback from Op:

> @KiloBatata There is another possibility, though: Use the xhtml
>   namspace instead of the native one. I have just tried it :
>
> `<h:li xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" sclass="@load(vm.className)" />`
>
> gives me
>
> `<li id="z_3" class="hello-world"></li>`

Using the xhtml namespace instead of the native one helped, as the native one does not create any widget or components for the DOM elements.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried your suggestion and the class isn't applied and I have checked and I putted a static `name_class` and it did work (Example : `<h:li class="active" />`), is there any other solution, thank you

Comment: Sorry that it did not help. I have read [some more about native namspace](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/HTML_Tags/The_native_Namespace), and it seems that you cannot update native components via server side logic after creating them because zk does not create a "component" on the server side (and not even a widget on the client). The only way to update those is with javascript.

Comment: @KiloBatata There is another possibility, though: [Use the xhtml namspace instead of the native one](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Languages#Mix_two_or_more_languages_in_a_ZUML_document). I have just tried it : `<h:li xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" sclass="@load(vm.className)" />` gives me `<li id="z_3" class="hello-world"></li>`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have tried your suggestion and it worked only if I put a static string like `sclass="@load('active')` but when I use `sclass="@load(vm.className)`

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Did the error message change? Does your viewModel have a method `getClassName()`? Is it called `vm`?

Comment: No it was my fault, My idea was to bind the class to a variable so when I change the variable the class changes also but that can't happen